# Looping repetitive commands

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got some data from a JSON and I am reprocessing it to put in an SQLlite table.

```
dane=json.loads(ws.recv())

typtranzakcji=dane.get('type',None)
kupsprzedaj=dane.get('side',None)
orderid=dane.get('order_id',None)

c.execute( "INSERT INTO Subskribe(type, side, order_id) VALUES (?,?,?)",
            (typtranzakcji, kupsprzedaj, orderid)
            )
```

this method is ok if the number of items is small. But I know it will only grow bigger, so I want something like this:

```
dane=json.loads(ws.recv())
for s in range(0,11,1):
    for a, b in ('typtranzakcji','type'),('kupsprzedaj','side'),('orderid','order_id'):
        a[s]=dane.get(b[s], None)

c.execute( "INSERT INTO Subskribe(type, side, price) VALUES (?,?,?)",
            (typtranzakcji, kupsprzedaj, cena)
            )
```

But something that does not give me an error of:

> `'str' object does not support item assignment`

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong with my loop?

Comment: take one iteration. a='orderid'. you're trying to do 'orderid'[2] = dane...

Comment: @user1087310 ok i was thinking that with the  [s] value controls from with bracket data is taken to the equation. but apparently I don't need it. But fixing this small bug still does not make the loop work how i want. the code just changes values of [a] and [b] i was hoping for a loop that takes creates variables with names from one place (a=[typtranzakcji], [kupsprzedaj], [orderid]) and gives them the corresponding value a=dane.get(['type'],['side'],['order_id']